# Как вывести переменную scss в сниппете vs code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, сниппет

Есть сниппет, при его вызове он определяет var как будто это положение курсора, как сделать так, чтобы этого не происходило, пробовал добавить еще $ перед var - не получилось.

```
{
    "": {
        "scope": "scss",
        "prefix": "mdcn",
        "body": [
            "@media (max-width: $var) {",
            "\t$0",
            "}"
        ],
        "description": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение.

```
{
    "": {
        "scope": "scss",
        "prefix": "mdcn",
        "body": [
            "@media (max-width: \\$var) {",
            "\t$0",
            "}"
        ],
        "description": ""
    }
}
```